# How can I transfer incomplete torrents from Vuze to uTorrent?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent, vuze

I want to switch my torrent client from [Vuze](http://www.vuze.com/) to [uTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/), but I have several downloads in progress. Is there any way I can move my incomplete downloads between clients?

Comment: May want to look for some other torrent client, utorrent is getting ads soon, thus becoming adware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the incomplete file for that torrent for Vuze and move it to where uTorrent stores it's incomplete files. Then load the `.torrent` file into uTorrent.

It *should* start the torrent recognizing that it's already partially downloaded.